# Copying a set of text to its corresponding files

Tags: notepad++, copy-paste

I have a set of text (eg: Apple, Bird, Car) and I want to add it to its corresponding file (eg: Fruit file, Animal file, Vehicle file) respectively. In simpler terms:

Copying

Apple into --> Fruit file

Bird into --> Animal file

Car into --> Vehicle file

I have a long list of this, so copying and pasting it one by one is just too tiring and more importantly, boring.

I am using Notepad ++, but please do let me know if there is any other software that will do the trick.

[EDIT] I was thinking about using principle of arrays, but could not figure out how.

Comment: How do you know Apple is a fruit? Why not a vehicle?

Comment: As Toto said, In order to proceede, you need some information (on a new text file, for example) that let's you map items with categories.

Comment: Sorry, I was busy for the last few days. As for your query, in my case there isnt any information in the file that will map the items.